# Is the performance of SQL procedure with multiple queries & loop better than nested SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I am facing a task that I can achieve in both an entire nested SQL and SQL procedure of multiple statements. I am wondering which one I should choose according to performance and how can I evaluate & compare them.

Here is my case. Some of my customers have changed their names and my task is to update the column **NAME** of my **CUSTOMER** table through a **MAPPING** table containing **OLD_NAME** and **NEW_NAME**.

I can write a nested SQL

```
update CUSTOMER set NAME = (select NEW_NAME from MAPPING where OLD_NAME = NAME) 
where NAME in (select OLD_NAME from MAPPING)
```

Procedure of queries with loop and condition

```
for record as
  select NAME from CUSTOMER
do
  select NEW_NAME into newName from MAPPING where OLD_NAME = record.NAME;
  if newName is not NULL then
    update CUSTOMER set NAME = newName where NAME = record.NAME;
  end if;
end do;
```

Of course, for the second one, I'd better make the update statement cached with prepare and execute.

My question is which one is better. Or both are stupid, then can you give me a better one?
May I know how to analyze their performance?

Personally, I think the procedure one is better, since the nested SQL have to scan MAPPING table twice (where & set clause), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, performing one update on a set of data is going to have much better performance than performing multiple individual updates.

There are several reasons for this.  The first is transactional overhead.  Each update has transactional overhead, so you greatly minimize this by doing one update instead of many.

This transactional overhead would be even more noticeable if you have indexes defined on the table.  Doing multiple individual index insertions is generally much slower than doing one larger index insertion.

Second, DB2 can take advantage of parallelism within queries.  However, a loop imposes sequential operations.

Third, doing the work in the loop may require moving data from the "database context" to the "loop execution context" -- that is, between two processes.  Such data movement would be an unnecessary overhead.  For instance, you might be running the code using a client-interface, in which case each row needs to be returned to the client.

And, another reason that is not specifically related to performance.  By doing the work in one query you have a single transaction should something go wrong (say, the machine gets rebooted).  Either all the updates occur or none of them.  The transaction semantics are different for a sequence of updates (although you could wrap the updates in another transaction).

Comment: Thanks, so if only performance is considered, I should always use a nested SQL. However,for the last reason, I think 'all or none' is not an advantage. It may depend on requirements. For an example, within sequence of updates/inserts, I can commit every thousands of changes using a counter for a large amount of data. Therefore, if any accidents occurred, I can continue from where I stopped and keep my previous efforts.

Comment: "wrap the updates in another transaction"...do you mean I can write a procedure including all updates and only commit the procedure while the whole procedure is done?

Comment: For a very large number of updates in a active productions DB, a series of small updates (with check point restart) would be desirable (instead of the one big transaction).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "always use nested SQL", as there may sometimes be better techniques that allow something to be performed in a single statement.  I tend to work with common table expressions and joins more often.  But as a rough rule of thumb, the fewer statements needed, the better.

Comment: @WarrenT I see, thanks. Could you give me a sample that we'd better use single statement rather than nest them into one?

Comment: I'll put one on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and give the link here when I come across a good one.  Or perhaps someone else has an example.

Comment: I have found that using the CTE format is a useful way to break a complex query down into conceptual blocks, helping someone else understand the logic.  I can teach other developers this one versatile pattern, and they get tremendous mileage out of it.  If check the FROM clause in the Info Center you'll see that nested table expressions have limitations which I don't encounter with CTE's.